# File Modes in Binary

Tags: c, file

Well I was looking into ways to open a file in binary and I saw that you can open one for r+b and a+b but whats the difference because this is what it says for definition.

a+b :Open a file for both reading and writing in binary mode.
r+b: Open a file for both reading and writing in binary mode.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: in "a+b" case file position will be on the end of file, in "r+b" - at the start.

Comment: @MichaelWalz your ref did answer my question should of post as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**a+b**
Open  for  reading and appending (writing at end of file).  The file is created if it does not exist.  The initial file position for reading is at the beginning of the file, but output is always appended to the end of the file.

**r+b** Open for reading and writing.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

**w+b**  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

So, a+b will create the file if it does not exist, and it will append to the file when you write to it,

r+b will not create the file if it doesn't already exist (fopen() would fail), and writing to the file will start at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Thank you because i realized that in my program i had a+b and it would not allow me to write to a record that was already in the file but after reading the explanations i realize that r+b is what i need.